# Painting a Gradient inside an Image by tapping in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an animal image and that image have a white background and the shape of animal is black outline. That is fixed on my image view in my .xib.

Now I would like to paint on the image, however only on the particular closed part.

Suppose a user touches on the hand then only hands will fill the gradient. The rest of the image will remain the same.

```
- (UIImage*)imageFromRawData:(unsigned char *)rawData
{
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * self.imageDoodle.image.size.width;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self.imageDoodle.image CGImage];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,self.imageDoodle.image.size.width,
    self.imageDoodle.image.size.height,bitsPerComponent,bytesPerRow,colorSpace, 
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return rawImage;
 }

-(unsigned char*)rawDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    NSLog(@"w=%d,h=%d",width,height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return rawData;
}
```

Where would I need to change my code to support this?

This is possible by `UIBezierPath` but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

Comment: Flood fill but i do this by uibezierpath.i read every thing but i don't understand how to apply that to my code.I google lot but didn't find any code.

Comment: Please post the code that does the fill.

Comment: ok this two method i am using for get the irreguler shape of image and fill color.